# derivating input output relationship of a block diagram when there is noise added to the output

Tags: control-systems

For the following system, I am not quite sure how the equation representing the input output relation is derived.
Here, r is an input reference signal, $d_e$ is external disturbance and $n$ is noise. What I can write is
$G[K(-Hy + Fr)+G_dd_e]+n = y$
so
$(1+GKH)y = GKFr + GG_dd_e +n$
so $y = F\frac{GK}{(1+GKH)}r + G_d\frac{G}{(1+GKH)} + \frac{1}{(1+GKH)}n$
however, the correct answer for the $\frac{1}{(1+GKH)}n$ term seems to be
$\frac{GKH}{(1+GKH)}n$? What have I done wrong?

[image: block diagram]

Comment: I don't see any mistake in your reasoning, seems like the given equation is wrong. Have another few pairs of eyes look over it ...